# SQL syntax error 'Incorrect syntax near 'UNSIGNED'.'

Tags: mysql

I have mysql2, inquirer, and console.table installed. I seems to be getting multiple errors when trying to create a table within my schema file.I have tried to reinstall all my packages to no avail. I have yet to create the seeds file as I thought i could knock the schema out of the way first if that might be whats causing the problem. [Multiple errors in Schema file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IL5B.png)

Comment: Post code as formatted text, not as a picture. *I have **mysql2*** What is it?

Comment: SQL code itself is correct (at least 1st `CREATE TABLE` statement: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=41809f243b57541a9fdf11e221f9af8e)). Maybe this is inquirer and/or console.table issue?

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to MySQL? The error message sounds more like you are using (Microsoft) SQL server.